# Magento v1.9 running on Linux - Order canceled, but NOT canceled

Tags: orders

Order shows Canceled, order acknowledgement email NOT sent, but the money was deposited in my account.  Customer did NOT cancel the order, but it looks like the item quantity was changed from 1 to 0.  Same customer successfully placed an order a few hours previously.  Other customer's orders before and after this one had no issues.  [image]Attached annotated screen shot explains it better.

Payments are via PayPal Payments Advanced.

I am the site owner and not a developer so please keep that in mind in your explanations.  THANKS!